# Is there a way to bind the xaml properties of an element to a new element created by code? (c# xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**XAML File Content**

```
 <StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="First app in c#" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pbstatus" ProgressColor="LightGreen"  Progress="0.01"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Actual Code (initializing variables)**

```
    int countvar = 0;
    string buttoncontains = "Click Me";
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar { ProgressColor = Color.LightGreen, Progress = 0 };
```

[The Progressbar above the buttons is the one made by the xaml file, 
the otherone created in the code is not shown or binded to the element, 
for any reason i cant use the progressbar made in the xaml file.](http://prntscr.com/qnafyf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add Control by C# to the layout, you can give a name for your StackLayout in xaml.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="sl">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="First app in c#" 
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pbstatus" ProgressColor="LightGreen"   Progress="0.01" />
</StackLayout>
```

Then, add the control(used `sl.Children.Add()`) by C# in the backend code,

```
        string buttoncontains = "Click Me";
        Button button = new Button() {Text= buttoncontains };
        button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;

         ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar { ProgressColor = 
         Color.LightGreen, Progress = 0 };


        sl.Children.Add(button);
        sl.Children.Add(progressBar);
```

Button click event

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbstatus.Progress = pbstatus.Progress+0.01;
    }
```

I bind the Button's text(Button created by C#) to the pbstatus's Progress(pbstatus created by xaml),

I used following code.

```
button.BindingContext = pbstatus;
button.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "Progress");
```

here is running gif.

[image]

Here is a helpful article about binding, you can refer to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings

Comment: Thats exactly what i've tried, its still not working.
 and the following came out :

http://prntscr.com/qnbhb9

But thanks anyways

Comment: I post my demo to github, please wait a minutes.

Comment: @Seby_Plays Here is my demo  https://github.com/851265601/BindingProgress

Comment: Coud my demo running normally? If yes, Please share your demo about it?

Comment: Did you add ` x:Name="sl"` to the `StackLayout `? If added it, please click the Ctrl+s to save this layout.

Comment: Your demo could've worked absolutely, on my side there were only SDK errors, which was the reason I couldn't execute it.

Comment: But otherwise there was nothing negatively highlighted. And I've already added a name to stacklayout. Anyways, I will upload my code to github later in the day roundabout 6pm(German timezone, if it's not too late on your side) like requested.

Comment: You can try to update your nuget packages to the latest.Then delete all of the `bin` and `obj` folders. rebuild you project, if this issue is still existed.